# css active feature not working

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have the  menu bar below and i would like to change the css class to active of the html code when the pages has been selected. So when the user has selected to view said page i would like to set the active class which is already set

HTML Code

```
<div id="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear-both">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
#main-nav{
    height:29px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(../Styles/images/nav-bg.gif);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:top left;
    width:100%;
}

#main-nav ul,
#main-nav li{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

#main-nav ul{
    height:29px;
    line-height:29px;
    background-image:url(../Styles/images/nav-bar.gif);
    background-position:right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    float:left;
    padding:0px 1px 0px 0px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#main-nav li{
    height:29px;
    line-height:29px;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:80px;
    text-align:center;
}

#main-nav li a{
    height:29px;
    width:80px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(../Styles/images/nav-bar.gif);
    background-position:left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}



#main-nav li a:link,
#main-nav li a:visited{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#main-nav li.active a,
#main-nav li a:hover{
    background-image:url(../Styles/images/active.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left;
}
```

Comment: Is there no javascript setting the active class to the clicked li?

Comment: The `.active` class should be set in your ASP code while generating the HTML. The CSS is irrelevant for this question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried a:active which does not work and i dont know what else can be tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to making list-based menus:

1. DO NOT STYLE THE LIST (other than display, position and float and clearing margins and padding)
2. Use `display:block` and put ALL STYLING on the `A`-tag (this includes your hover and active states).

Also, choose `display:inline-block`, or `float:left`, not both.